# How to insert the SQL Error message into table

Tags: mysql, transactions, sqlexception

I want to store the error messages which occurs while executing the stored procedure in another error table.
Here is the my sample procedure having some error statements.

```
    DELIMITER $$
    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `test`$$
    CREATE PROCEDURE `test`()
    BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM emp;

    END $$
    DELIMITER $$;
```

When i call the above procedure it gives me error.I wnat to store this error code & message in another table as "error".
Any pointers are appreciated.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to handle this in MySQL is to declare a `HANDLER` to handle the error condition the way you want. This allows you to insert an error message into another table if you want, and then to either `CONTINUE` or `EXIT` the running procedure as required.

Here's the documentation:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/declare-handler.html

Unfortunately you will not be able to access the SQLSTATE of the statement that caused the error, so this approach is somewhat limited.

Here's another relevant question on SO with much more detail:

[MySQL Stored Procedure Error Handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7764887/mysql-stored-procedure-error-handling)

Answer (score 0):

**SQL ERROR** means there is something wrong with your SQL Query. It may (or may not) depend on your table. If the error is **TABLE SPECIFIC** or **QUERY SYNTAX ERROR**, that is, if there is something wrong with a specific table ONLY, or with a query, then definitely you can insert your errors into a table. But, if there is something with your **CONNECTION** or something else, then you cannot insert errors into any table.
**ALWAYS** try to log your errors in a `html` file or `txt` (text) file, so that you can smoothly access it. Also there is a less chance for failure.