# Return Exception from MySQL stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, exception

I am using following Exception handler in my stored procedure.

```
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
    
Begin
      DROP TABLE temp_checkForDuplicate;
      SET outDone = -1;
End;
```

Here I found some code for particular

> exception '1062'
>
> DECLARE EXIT handler for 1062 set o_error_status := "Duplicate entry in table";

What if I don't know the exception number: How to handle any exception and throw its number and its message?

Comment: I think we need more info of the SP, sometimes the error could be in other place

Comment: error can be any where.. thats y we use the handler then how to get that??

Answer (score 0):

In versions of MySQL prior to 5.5 you cannot really do this.

Version 5.5 has introduced Signals which provide a mechanism to return specific error codes or conditions.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html

Version 5.6 has added "Get Diagnostics" which provides the information you need.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/get-diagnostics.html

You can also find related information in these SO Questions.

[MySQL Stored Procedure Error Handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7764887/mysql-stored-procedure-error-handling)

[How to raise an error within a MySQL function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/465727/raise-error-within-mysql-function)