# Python: MySQL batch inserting, skip entries where foreign key constraint fails

Tags: python, mysql, sql, batch-file

I have designed a large DB with foreign key constraints, in order to prevent the insertion of corrupted data, which violates those constraints. I was hoping, when I'm inserting my data with Python, it would just skip every entry, where the foreign key contraints fail, so that only the "real" data is inserted in the database. Kinda like a filter. However, the script stops whenever a "corrupted" entry occurs. Is there any way to force him to continue and just skip the unwanted lines?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...` to make a conditional insert. Let's make an example: There are two tables *country* and *city*, and the column `country_id` from `city` references to corresponding column from *country*.

- `country(country_id,name)`
- `city(city_id,name,country_id)`

The following `INSERT` statement inserts the entry unconditionally. It fails if there exists no row in *country* with the value of `:country_id`.

```
INSERT INTO city (city_id, name, country_id)
          VALUES (:city_id, :name, :country_id);
```

The following statement only inserts the entry, if a corresponding row in *country* exists. Otherwise, nothing happens.

```
INSERT INTO city (city_id, name, country_id)
       SELECT :city_id, :name, :country_id
       FROM country
       WHERE country_id=:country_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use handlers:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/declare-handler.html

And choose `continue` option

Few handlers examples:

[MySQL Stored Procedure Error Handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7764887/mysql-stored-procedure-error-handling)