# MySQL how to return "SHOW ERRORS" in stored function

Tags: php, mysql, stored-functions

I have the following stored function in which I'd like to handle errors. I can't find a way to make SHOW ERRORS working. I know why this isn't working: the "SHOW ERROR" will not return a single value, but I can't a way to find a solution.

```
DROP function if exists error_handling;
delimiter $$
CREATE FUNCTION error_handling (n varchar(100), id int)
RETURNS varchar(1000) DETERMINISTIC
begin
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR sqlexception return(show errors);
    update ts_my_table SET name = n where my_id=id;
RETURN (SELECT ROW_COUNT());
end; $$
```

I'd like to return the message of the eventual error.
I was thinking something like

```
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR sqlexception return(select message from show errors);
```

but it's not working...
The problem is that I can't find any hint related to stored function, all I can find is how to resolve it in stored procedure. I need to return the error message because I'm using a stored function.

Thanks very much

Comment: Possible Duplicate?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7764887/mysql-stored-procedure-error-handling

Comment: It's for stored procedure, I read that question but it doesn't help me find the solution.